# Get monthly NDVI and NDWI median for a year, from Landsat collection Google Earth Engine (GEE)

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, landsat-8, normalized-difference-water-index, imagecollection

I am trying to get NDVI and NDWI per month, based on the median of the images in one month. For this, I am using Landsat8 collection an year 2018. I keep getting empty bands for the `var monthlyStats`. I think that the problem is the timestamp. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
function calculateNDVI(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
}
function calculateNDWI(image) {
  return image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B5']).rename('NDWI');
}

var landsat8 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterBounds(area)
  .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 20))
  .select(['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7']);
print('landsat8', landsat8);


var withNDVI = landsat8.map(calculateNDVI);
var withNDWI = landsat8.map(calculateNDWI);
var combined = withNDVI.combine(withNDWI);
print('combined', combined);


var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

function filterByMonth(month) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(2018, ee.Number(month), 1);
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'month');
  return combined.filterDate(startDate, endDate);
}

var monthlyStats = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  months.map(function (m) {
    var monthImages = filterByMonth(m);
    return monthImages.median().set('month', m);
  })
);
print('monthlyStats', monthlyStats);

var firstMonthImage = ee.Image(monthlyStats.first());
Map.addLayer(firstMonthImage, { bands: ['NDVI_median', 'NDWI_median', 'B4_median'], min: -0.1, max: 0.8 });

Export.image.toDrive({
  collection: monthlyStats,
  description: 'NDVI_NDWI_monthly',
  scale: 30,
  region: area,
  maxPixels: 1e10
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
      .filterDate('2018-01-01', '2018-12-31')
      .filterBounds(area)
      .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 50));
      
print(imageCollection);

// Adding a NDVI band

function addNDVI(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']).rename('ndvi');
  var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B4']).rename('ndwi');
  return image.addBands([ndvi]).addBands([ndwi]);
}

var ndvi = imageCollection.map(addNDVI);
print(ndvi);

var months = ee.List.sequence(1, 12);

// Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// month.
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
  months.map(function (m) {
    return ndvi.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                .select(['ndvi', 'ndwi']).median()
                .set('month', m);
}));
print(byMonth);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()));

// Visualizar una capa mensual
var firstMonthImage = ee.Image(byMonth.first());
Map.addLayer(firstMonthImage, { bands: ['ndvi', 'ndwi', 'ndvi'], min: -0.1, max: 0.8 });
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly !